# put large number of equally sized ImageViews in a row

Tags: android, layout, imageview

Within a layout I want to put 11 equally sized (more or less quadratic) ImageViews in a row. Only one of them shall be displayed at a point in time. It is crucial that the ImageView number x starts EXACTLY at x/11 of the screen width. This might sound trivial, but after some attempts and research I'm not so sure anymore.

What I tried so far is using a horizontal Linear Layout, putting 11 ImageViews in it and applying

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="0.0909"
```

to each of them and set visibility to VISIBLE for one of them and to INVISIBLE for all others in the code. Unfortunately this solution is not really reliable and I see that the position of the ImageViews vary slightly.

Another attempt, using the displayed ImageView as thumb of a seekbar and setting the seekbar's progress to number x was also not great on all devices I tested.

What is the best practice here to get stable results? Thanks in advance.